# how to extract these fields via sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to grep for individual quantities in lines like this:

```
foo=24.587 bar=88 fox=jobs
```

and extract, say, all the '88' values..the number of columns isn't consistent so awk followed by a cut wont cut it.

I tried using sed like this:

```
sed -e 's/.*\s\(bar=.+\)\s.*/\1/g'
```

and that just dumps the entire line. I'm not sure how to correct this regexp, and more importantly why this regexp doesnt do what I expect?

Comment: Are you trying to match `bar=88` or `=88` and would you require potentially multiple matches per line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-r` (extended regex).  This tends to use regexen more like you may expect.  You have to remove the backslashes from the parens, though:

```
$ echo "foo=24.587 bar=88 fox=jobs" | sed -r 's/.*\s(bar=.+)\s.*/\1/g'
bar=88
```

Comment: Cool! Interestingly enough, if I do this:
echo "tau=39.05 dos=200 iv=2 bar=39.05 foo=39.06  fox=jobs" | sed -r 's/.*\s(bar=.+)\s.*/\1/g' I get the bar and the foo!

Comment: @PalaceChan use `'s/.*\s(bar=[^ ]+)\s.*/\1/g'`.  Unfortunately, `sed` does not allow for reluctant quantifiers

Comment: I see, trixy trixy. THanks

Comment: @ExplosionPills since you have `.*` as the final part of you regexp the `g` flag on the substitute command will only ever match once at most. Also if you are using GNU sed `\S+` matches one or more  non-spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/.*\s(bar=.+)\s.*/\1/g'
```